# Run 12/3 through insulated wall to surface mounted electric panel

Tags: receptacle, garage, subpanel, wire

Should/can I run the 12/3 wire inside the wall or just run a conduit up to the attic?

[image]

The project:

I want to install split receptacle 20 amp outlets in my garage. The subpanel in the garage is surface mounted to a finished and insulated wall. The other walls in the garage are not finished. So my plan is to run the wire up to the attic and then feed it through the unfinished walls to the outlets.

Comment: Haven't we seen this panel before? Looks very familiar. And you can't run 20 A circuits on 14 Ga wire under NEC rules, regardless. You were told 12 GA last time. https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/171564/18078

Comment: @Ecnerwal - thanks, I meant 12/3. I've updated it now